# Display a fullscreen camera in XNA

Tags: camera, windows-phone-7.1, fullscreen, xna-4.0, windows-phone

all, I want to display a fullscreen camera(Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera) in Windows Phone with XNA, as the following code showed, I tried to change the value of screenpos and origin, but it didn't work, what's wrong with my code? Thanks

```
 if (CameraTexture != null)
        {
            Vector2 origin = new Vector2(CameraTexture.Width / 2, CameraTexture.Height / 2);
            Vector2 screenpos = new Vector2(240, 400);
            spriteBatch.Draw(CameraTexture, screenpos, null, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.White, (float)Math.PI / 2,
           origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle rec = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(0, 0, (int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight);
```

spriteBatch.Draw(texture, rec, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.White);